# replace starting characters in string

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string in which i need to replace the starting set of characters with `mod1`.
Its like `xyz_gf_111_yz` to `mod1_111_yz`.
         `bcd_df_222_xx` to `mod2_222_xx` and so on.

can anybody suggest sol, as the starting string is not fixed and im beginner in perl

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     my @strings = qw(xyz_gf_111_yz bcd_df_222_xx asd_cv_333_dd); 
     my $i = 1;

     for my $str (@strings)
     {   
         my $after = $str;

         $after =~ s/^\w{3}[_]\w{2}/mod$i/;
         $i++;
         print "$str -> $after\n";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following could get you started:

```
my @strings = qw(xyz_gf_111_yz bcd_df_222_xx);

my $i = 0;
for my $str (@strings) {
    my $after = $str;
    $i++;
    $after =~ s/[^_]+/mod$i/;

    print "$str -> $after\n";
}
```

Comment: yes,but i was trying something below $var = ~s/^\s+.*(\d+)/$1/; But this is giving me xyz_gf_mod1 instead of mod1_111_yz and so on. Could you please let me know how this can be fixed.

Comment: your regex is greedy search, which means it will match the last instance of the string.
To make it non-greedy, use $var = ~s/^\s+.*?(\d+)/$1/

Comment: This is again giving me mod1 at the end instead at the beginning: bcd_df_mod1 instead i need it to be mod1_222_xx

Answer (score 0):

@Miller,

I suggest a different solution, assuming that you want to replace the starting substring (all chars to the left the first digit) and the associated digit to the "mod" string is given by the first digit of the number substring the following could be a way.

```
my @strings = qw(xyz_gf_111_yz bcd_df_222_xx asd_cv_333_dd); 

for my $str (@strings) {
    print "bfr:".$str."\n";
    $str =~ s/^([^\d]+?)_(\d)/mod$2_$2/;
    print "aft:".$str."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i;
my @strings = ( 'xyz_gf_111_yz', 'bcd_df_222_xx' );

for (@strings) {
    print $_, "\n" if s/.+?_[^_]+/'mod'.++$i/e;
}
```

Output:

```
mod1_111_yz
mod2_222_xx
```